# Why does Toast.makeText is not accepting formatted text?

Tags: android, android-studio, toast

Being a begginer in android , i have been stuck while using Toast.makeText ,here is the code.

```
public class CustomOnSelectedListen implements OnItemSelectedListener{

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos,long id){
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
            "OnItemSelectedListener :" + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){
     Toast.makeText(CustomOnSelectedListen.this,"Please select place and class".toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

}

and the error is

```
Error:(19, 15) error: no suitable method found for  
       makeText(CustomOnSelectedListen,String,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; CustomOnSelectedListen cannot be converted to Context)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; CustomOnSelectedListen cannot be converted to Context)
```

Here CustomOnSelectedListen cannot be converted, what might be wrong?

**EDIT 1**: Yes CustomOnSelectedListen was not an context instance , i need to display a message in the function onNothingSelected() using toast,what are the different ways to do it?

Comment: **CustomOnSelectedListen cannot be converted to Context** get the hint..Check the direct subclasses and indirect subclasses at the top  @ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html.

Comment: You need to pass **context instance** as a first parameter in your makeText method, not **CustomOnSelectedListen instance**.

Comment: In which class you are printing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `onNothingSelected` function:

```
Toast.makeText(CustomOnSelectedListen.this,"Please select place and class".toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

First parameter (`CustomOnSelectedListen.this`)  is not a `Context` instance.